# Operación delete en una api rest usando Spring Boot

Tags: api, spring

En algunos artículos me indican que si el recurso no existe se debe retornar un código de estado 404. Sin embargo, en otros me indican que debe ser 204(No Content), ya que la operación de borrado se asegura de que el recurso indicado no exista en el sistema. Por ello, si se intenta eliminar un recurso inexistente, no se devuelve un 404, pues la operación se considera correcta.¿Cual debería ser el código de estado en una respuesta si el recurso que se quiere eliminar no existe en el sistema?

Comment: Tu mismo has respondido a tu pregunta. Dado que es una API que estás haciendo tu, eres libre de elegir qué quieres que responda exactamente tu servicio y con qué estado. Personalmente yo prefiero un 404 porque no es que no haya contenido.. es que no existe. Pero como decía... tu api, tus reglas. No hay nada obligándote a usar un 404 o 204, lo más importante es la consistencia. El que elijas devolver será el que uses en el resto de servicios de tu api! Lo demás... documéntalo y listo

Answer (score 0):

Ciertamente hay algunos [códigos de respuesta HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) que son algo ambiguos.

Los código 2XX son cuando la operación se ha realizado correctamente. No es posible borrar algo que no existe, por lo que nunca la operación "borrar" se va a ejecutar, por lo que el uso de cualquier código 2XX en este escenario es incorrecto.

Desde el punto de vista del cliente que consume tu API, debe ser capaz de detectar que hay algo incorrecto en su solicitud (algo estará ingresando mal para que intente borrar algo que no existe). Muchas funcionalidades de consumo tales como `fetch` de javascript y `HttpClient` de C# cuentan con una propiedad `Response.ok` que es `true` cuando recibe un código 2XX y `false` en cualquier otro caso. Esto permite separar los casos correctos e incorrectos fácilmente, por ejemplo un mensaje de "se ha borrado el dato" y otro "Error: no se ha podido borrar"

Entonces en este caso un código `404` sería más correcto, y según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#information_responses):

> El servidor no puede encontrar el recurso solicitado. En el navegador,
> esto significa que no se reconoce la URL. **En una API, esto también**
> **puede significar que el punto de conexión es válido, pero el recurso**
> **en sí no existe**.

En último caso un [error 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) también podría ser valido, el cual indica que el cliente ha enviado una solicitud incorrecta.